# $G$-analogues of symmetric functions (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, symmetric-functions

Let $G$ be a simple graph with vertex set $V$. [Stanley](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/taor.pdf) defined the $G$-analogs of the symmetric function as follows:
For $i \ge 0$, define $$e^G_i = \sum_S \big(\prod_{v \in S}v\big)$$ where the sum runs over independent /stable subsets of size $i$ in $G$.

Since the classical elementary symmetric functions $e_{i}$ form a basis for the ring of symmetric functions $e_{i}$ goes to $e^G_{i}$ defines a homomorphism from ring of symmetric functions to $\mathbb{Z}(V)$. Using this homomorphism, we can define $G$-analogs of other classical symmetric functions also.

I want to learn more about this combinatorial object. Kindly suggest some references. Thank you.

Comment: One good place to look would be the [41 papers](https://mathscinet.ams.edu/mathscinet/search/publications.html?refcit=1661374) that MSN knows reference [Stanley's](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1661374).